# Xcode environment variable to project directory with SPM

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an `Xcode` project and would like to add a Build Phase Run Script to run a script that's inside a package i'm using.
With CocoaPods i could do something like this -
`bash "$SOURCE_ROOT/Pods/myFramework/script.sh`.
I changed the dependency to use Swift Package Manager, so now i need to change the path to be something like this -
`/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name/SourcePackages/checkouts/myFramework/script.sh`.
what would be the equivalent of SOURCE_ROOT to get to the project inside DerivedData?
I don't want to set a local environment variable as this should be a out of the box ready for other developers on every mac

Comment: So you want to access resources inside a swift package from xcode?

Comment: Try this : ```${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/myFramework/script.sh```

Comment: @RajaKishan this worked! thank you, please feel free to put it as an answer so i can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your path like this

```
${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/myFramework/script.sh
```

[here](https://forums.swift.org/t/adding-an-executable-spm-dependency-in-xcode-11/28841/12) is the source of the answere.

Comment: This is no longer working for me in Xcode 14.1.  Is this working for others?

Comment: Not working Xcode 14.2. Is there a solution compatible with recent Xcode versions?

Comment: You can use dot-path to go up a directory or a few. Whereas `${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}` would remove anything after "Build/" inclusively (usually "Build/Products") you could rely on "../../" to remove both unwanted subdirectories from your path (e.g. `$BUILD_DIR/../../SourcePackages/checkouts/myFramework/script.sh`).

Comment: It seems the percent syntax `%Build` only works in a Bash-Shell. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333612/having-trouble-understanding-xcode-build-parameter-build-dirbuild) for reference.