# Having trouble understanding xcode build parameter: "${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm integrating the [WireGuardKit](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-apple/about/), according to its README file, I need to create an external build system target to build wireguard-go-bridge library.

In the external build system target's info tab. The documentation says I should use this location: `${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo` 
The build for the external build system target failed. As the path can't be resolved.
If I change the path with a correct, absolute path, the build will succeed.

Can anyone tell me what's the meaning of this `${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}`, looks firebase is also using this magic variable, see [Firebase Crashlytics | Swift Package Manager (SPM) Run Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410459/firebase-crashlytics-swift-package-manager-spm-run-script)

Answer (score 6):

After some googling, I figured it out:
Quote SuperUser contributor Marek Rost's Post:

> When the percent sign (%) is used in the pattern ${variable%substring}, it will return content of the variable with the shortest occurrence of substring deleted from the back of the variable.

> This function supports wildcard patterns, that is why it accepts an asterisk (star) as a substitute for zero or more characters. It should be mentioned that this is Bash specific. Other Linux shells do not necessarily contain this function.

> If you want to learn more about string manipulation in Bash, then I highly suggest reading the following page, Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 10. Manipulating Variables. Among many other handy functions, it explains what a double percent sign (%%) does, for example.

> I forgot to mention that when it is used in the pattern $((variable%number)) or $((variable1%$variable2)), the percent sign (%) character will function as a modulo operator.

> When the percent sign (%) is used in different contexts, it should be recognized as a regular character only.

So suppose ${BUILD_DIR} is

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wgShowcase-dejirdnsktlwtagdrhljeefdnxvi/Build/Products
```

What ${BUILD_DIR%Build/*} mean is delete the shortest occurrence of substring `Build/*`(the star sign is a wildcard) from the back of ${BUILD_DIR} variable. In this case, the `Build/Products` will be removed. then we have the result:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wgShowcase-dejirdnsktlwtagdrhljeefdnxvi/
```

So since all the SPM packages used by this project checks out at a child directory at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wgShowcase-dejirdnsktlwtagdrhljeefdnxvi/`, the final resolved path should be:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wgShowcase-dejirdnsktlwtagdrhljeefdnxvi/SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo
```

As for why the build is not succeed, I think it's a Xcode bug. I have reported a bug to apple. For anyone who is trying to build.
Use below as a workaround:

```
${BUILD_DIR}/../../SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo
```

Update: Here is the response from Apple regarding to this 'issue'

> After reviewing your feedback, we have some additional information for you, or some additional information, or action is necessary for this issue:

> The Directory field here is not evaluated as a bash variable, it’s evaluated as an Xcode build setting, which does not support bash operators such as %.

> You would likely need to set the working directory to a known directory with a makefile, and then have that makefile use makefiles from the ultimate target directory.

> We noticed that when we clone the repo it comes with macOS and iOS targets whose directories are set to $(PROJECT_DIR)/Sources/WireGuardKitGo, so we're wondering if the project owner has updated the project to fix this issue, but hasn’t updated the documentation.

> In any event, this is behaving correctly.

Comment: The path is correct when compiling, but when I execute the archive, the path is still incorrect. Do you know what the correct path is?

Comment: @Rakuyo try using `${BUILD_DIR}/../../SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo`

Comment: I can't use this path to perform an archive operation. build operations are possible, but archive operations are not. My xcode version is 13.2.1. can you use this path to perform an archive operation?

Comment: @Rakuyo same Xcode version, I'm making the WireGuardKitGo as source code now.  This should give Xcode external build system a better&fixed directory path.

Comment: @kakaiikakaka When I try to integrate WireGuardKit as source code, I run into more compilation problems. I tried to do it like wireguard's app project, but I had a lot of difficulties... If you successfully integrate WireGuardKit as source code, I wonder if you can open source a demo? I believe it could help a lot of people.

Comment: @Rakuyo Check https://github.com/kasimok/wgShowcase-public

Comment: After I cloned this project of yours locally and configured the signature, I still can't package it. Same error as I had before... Can you perform the packaging operation in this project?

Comment: @Rakuyo I decided not to use the SPM, looks like the external build systems' path when we are doing archive is different in debugging time. So I ported the code as a local framework. Have Fun! Plz, pull the latest code. –  I forgot to push last week.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hadn't thought about integrating WireGuard into the project as a framework. This completely solved my problem, thank you so much indeed.